# Why is video player layer not centered?

Tags: swift, uikit

Unsure why this isn't playing centered. I made the UIView "holderView" red so as you can see the video is player layer or video layer object is uncentered, off to the right.

**This does not happen when**
`playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize`
instead of .resizeAspect

```
func addPlayerLayer(){
    guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "scan_animation", ofType: "mp4")
    else {
        print ("ERROR path for video not found")
        return
    }
    let videoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: holderView.frame.width, height: holderView.frame.height))
    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = videoView.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    holderView.addSubview(videoView)
    print("player layer frame \(playerLayer.frame)")
    print("player bounds \(playerLayer.bounds)")
    print("videoView frame \(videoView.frame)")
    print("videoView bounds \(videoView.bounds)")
    print("holderView frame \(holderView.frame)")
    print("holderView bounds \(holderView.bounds)")
}
```

Here's the printed output, everything seems centered, the holderView is 20 pixels in on leading and trailing):

```
player layer frame (0.0, 0.0, 374.0, 449.0)
player bounds (0.0, 0.0, 374.0, 449.0)
videoView frame (0.0, 0.0, 374.0, 449.0)
videoView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 374.0, 449.0)
holderView frame (20.0, 48.0, 374.0, 449.0)
holderView bounds (0.0, 0.0, 374.0, 449.0)
```

[image: off center view of video in simulator]

I tried various constraints.

Comment: You're not showing enough code. The key question is _when_ you call `addPlayerLayer`. I've got a dollar here that says you're doing it in some really bad place like `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That is correct, the view is added as part of viewDidload.  When should I add it?

Comment: Also, the first frame of the video needs to be on screen before the user hits the play button

Comment: Thanks matt, calling addPlayerLayer in viewDidAppear fixed the issue!

Comment: Yeah, that's not necessarily the best place, but better. Read my http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

calling addPlayerLayer in viewDidAppear fixed the issue

Comment: I would suggest just deleting the question. This is too well covered on Stack Overflow already to need another entry on the same topic.